# Is there a better way for variable declaration in if/else

Tags: javascript

I got this code in my project, but I'm not satisfied with it because same var declaration is repeating. Is there a better way to deal with it?

```
if (type == 1) {
    var addressId = data.address.BillingAddress.id;
    var addressTitle = data.address.BillingAddress.title;
    var $select = $('.billingAddressId');
    var $notification = $('.billingNotification');
} else {
    var addressId = data.address.DeliveryAddress.id;
    var addressTitle= data.address.DeliveryAddress.title;
    var $select = $('.deliveryAddressId');
    var $notification = $('.shippingNotification');
}
```

Comment: That code suggests there's a deeper issue in your data structure...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why dont you declare them before if-else block

```
var addressId, addressTitle, $select, $notification;
if ( type == 1 ) {
     addressId = data.address.BillingAddress.id;
     addressTitle = data.address.BillingAddress.title;
     $select = $('.billingAddressId');
     $notification = $('.billingNotification');
} else {
     addressId = data.address.DeliveryAddress.id;
     addressTitle= data.address.DeliveryAddress.title;
     $select = $('.deliveryAddressId');
     $notification = $('.shippingNotification');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, there is no need to do this. You would add 4 lines of unnecessary code.

Take the advantage of Javascript which allows you to do this, and keep it like it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic property:

```
var addressId = data.address[type==1 ? "BillingAddress" : "DeliveryAddress"].id,
    addressTitle = data.address[type==1 ? "BillingAddress" : "DeliveryAddress"].title,
    $select = $(type==1 ? '.billingAddressId' : '.deliveryAddressId'),
    $notification = $(type==1 ? '.billingNotification' : '.shippingNotification');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ditch the `if` and use [**short circuit evaluation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
var addressId = type === 1 && addressId = data.address.BillingAddress.id 
                           || data.address.DeliveryAddress.id;
/** ...etc **/
```

Or use a [**ternary operator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#JavaScript):

```
var addressId = type === 1 ? addressId = data.address.BillingAddress.id 
                           : data.address.DeliveryAddress.id;
/** ...etc **/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var addressId = "";
var addressTitle ="";
var $select = "";
var $notification="";
if (type == 1) {
               addressId = data.address.BillingAddress.id;
                addressTitle = data.address.BillingAddress.title;
                $select = $('.billingAddressId');
                $notification = $('.billingNotification');
            } else {
                addressId = data.address.DeliveryAddress.id;
                addressTitle= data.address.DeliveryAddress.title;
                $select = $('.deliveryAddressId');
                $notification = $('.shippingNotification');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare variables in the outer scope so that you can access them inside blocks..

```
var addressId = "";
var addressTitle = "";
var $select="";
var $notification="";

if (type == 1) {
    addressId = data.address.BillingAddress.id;
    addressTitle = data.address.BillingAddress.title;
    $select = $('.billingAddressId');
    $notification = $('.billingNotification');
} else {
    addressId = data.address.DeliveryAddress.id;
    addressTitle= data.address.DeliveryAddress.title;
    $select = $('.deliveryAddressId');
    $notification = $('.shippingNotification');
}
```

Comment: Globally is often a bad idea, in the outer scope is a good idea though.

Comment: Well that isn't globally and can easily be misinterpreted. It's better to just say that it should be declared in the outer scope.